# AWS EBS Java Options update

Tags: amazon-web-services, jvm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, javaoptions

How can I update default **JVM options** for AWS ElasticBeanstalk application (Spring Boot app)?

I have tried doing it with .ebextensions folder, however "JVM Options" parameter is "unrecognised" by the platform.

Another attempt I have tried was to use Configuration section and specify **Xmx** and **Xmx** (as well as **JVM Options** and **JAVA_OPTS**) there, but running application experiences no difference (have embedded some stat printing out at the start of the app).

In short - neither Configuration nor .ebextensions folder embedded in the WAR makes no difference to EBS runtime and hence to my app.

Looks like I have searched whole the web for the answer, but none of advised works and they all looks like either obsolete or not working.

AWS documentation is not clear in this regard as well.

Comment: By EBS do you mean Elastic Block Store or Elastic Beanstalk (I ask because they have separate tags, neither of which is "ebs").

Comment: It’s Elastic Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

We use [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-procfile.html) for this. E.g.

```
web: java -Dmy.port=1234 -jar my.jar
```

Comment: It doesn’t work either. Only default one is applied. Even if I change the default one, all alternations against ootb file configuration are ignored.

Comment: It does work for us without problems. Can you clarify what exactly you are doing and what "only default one is applied" means?